# Inequalities involving the cdf of a random variable

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose these two inequalities hold
$$
\begin{cases}
(1) \hspace{1cm}Pr(Y=y)\leq Pr(\epsilon\geq -a)\\
(2) \hspace{1cm}Pr(W=w)\leq Pr(\epsilon\leq -a)\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $Y,W$ are discrete random variable, $\epsilon$ is a continuous random variable with cdf $F$, and $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar.

Let $G$ be the cdf of $-\epsilon$. I am confused on whether I am allowed to do the following steps without making any particular assumption on $G$ (like symmetry around zero or similar).

$$
(1) \hspace{1cm} Pr(Y=y)\leq Pr(\epsilon\geq -a) \Leftrightarrow 
Pr(Y=y)\leq Pr(-\epsilon\leq a) \Leftrightarrow Pr(Y=y)\leq G(a) \Leftrightarrow G^{-1}(Pr(Y=y))\leq a
$$

$$
(2)  \hspace{1cm} Pr(W=w)\leq Pr(\epsilon\leq -a) \Leftrightarrow  Pr(W=w)\leq Pr(-\epsilon\geq a) \Leftrightarrow Pr(W=w)\leq 1-Pr(-\epsilon\leq a)\Leftrightarrow Pr(W=w)\leq 1-G(a)  \Leftrightarrow 1-Pr(W=w)\geq G(a) \Leftrightarrow G^{-1}(1-Pr(W=w))\geq a
$$

Hence
$$
G^{-1}(Pr(Y=y))\leq  a\leq G^{-1}(1-Pr(W=w))
$$

Comment: A continuous random variable is one for which the cdf is a continuous function. It is not necessary that a continuous cdf  has an inverse since it may be constant on some intervals. Hence use of $G^{-1}$ is not legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are fine.
\begin{align}
(1) &\hspace{1cm} Pr(Y=y)\leq Pr(\epsilon\geq -a) \\&\Leftrightarrow 
Pr(Y=y)\leq Pr(-\epsilon\leq a), (\text{since } \epsilon \ge -a \iff -\epsilon \le a)\\& \Leftrightarrow Pr(Y=y)\leq G(a) ,(\text{definition of }G) \\&\Leftrightarrow G^{-1}(Pr(Y=y))\leq a , (G \text{ and } G^{-1} \text{ are non-decreasing)}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
(2)  &\hspace{1cm} Pr(W=w)\leq Pr(\epsilon\leq -a) \\&\Leftrightarrow  Pr(W=w)\leq Pr(-\epsilon\geq a), (\text{since } \epsilon \ge -a \iff -\epsilon \le a)\\&  \Leftrightarrow Pr(W=w)\leq 1-Pr(-\epsilon\leq a), (\text{Since } -\epsilon \text{ is continuous})\\&\Leftrightarrow Pr(W=w)\leq 1-G(a),(\text{definition of }G)  \\& \Leftrightarrow 1-Pr(W=w)\geq G(a) \text{, (just algebra)}\\& \Leftrightarrow G^{-1}(1-Pr(W=w))\geq a , (G \text{ and } G^{-1} \text{are non-decreasing)}
\end{align}

Note that $G^{-1}$ refers to the generalized inverse distribution.